# Laravel 5.6 Passport FatalThrowableError on php artisan passport:install --force

Tags: laravel

I seem to be having a problem installing Laravel Passport, when running the command php artisan passport:install --force, I get the following error.

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Access to undeclared static property: Laravel\Passport\Passport::$client

at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxxxxxxxx/alpha.platform.vuex/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Passport.php:413

```
    409|      * @return \Laravel\Passport\Client
    410|      */
    411|     public static function client()
    412|     {
  > 413|         return new static::$client;
    414|     }
    415| 
    416|     /**
    417|      * Set the personal access client model class name.
```

Not sure what has happened since running this command last night when it was working fine.

Comment: Try running `composer update` and then `passport:install`...

Comment: Thanks i did try this, seems it could be a problem with the latests Passport build, will be posting my fix now.

Answer (score 3):

So i have found the problem.

Old composer

```
   "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^6.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
```

New composer

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/passport": "^4.0.3",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
},
```

Rolled back the passport version and all seems to work as planned.

** Edit 
After checking out the repo, updates where made 3 days back causing the break, now rolled back to 6.0.0 , this issue has been flagged on github.

Comment: You're right it is broken in passport 6.0.1, so it is better to stick, to the latest working  `"laravel/passport": "6.0.0",` in your composer...